# Creating dynamic forms and its validation react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I got this questions in my last live coding sometime ago, but couldn't complete it. I only manage to answer the first question, but went completely blank to answer the rest. So here is the question:

```
/**
 * 
 * Assuming we have fetched it from DYNAMIC_FORMS, there will be a forms 
 * dynamically generated. Your code need to handle if DYNAMIC_FORMS is changed with another 
 * requirements, with the assumption that the format will be like what you have seen 
 * below.
 * 
 * The goals are:
 * 1. Render the form dynamically based on the requirements below,
 * 2. Create JS validation that triggered upon clicking submit,
 *    (Note that we can just try the `required` validation first.)
 * 3. (Bonus point) refactor the validation logic where it will be triggered upon 
 *    leaving from 1 input to another input (by using tab on keyboard)
 * 
 */

const DYNAMIC_FORMS = [
  {
    texts: {
      header: 'Name Section'
    },
    inputs: [
      {
        label: 'Full Name',
        type: 'text',
        name: 'name',
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 4
        },
        error: 'Name is required'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    texts: {
      header: 'Password Section'
    },
    inputs: [
      {
        label: 'Password',
        type: 'password',
        name: 'password',
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 6,
          maxLength: 10
        },
        error: 'Password is required'
      },
      {
        label: 'Pincode',
        type: 'number',
        name: 'pincode',
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 6,
          maxLength: 6
        },
        error: 'Invalid Pincode'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    texts: {
      header: 'Address Section'
    },
    inputs: [
      {
        label: 'Address Line 1',
        type: 'text',
        name: 'addressLine1',
        validation: {
          required: true
        },
        error: 'Invalid Address'
      },
      {
        label: 'Address Line 2',
        type: 'text',
        name: 'addressLine2',
        validation: {
          required: false
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'Zipcode',
        type: 'number',
        name: 'zipcode',
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 6,
          maxLength: 7
        },
        error: 'Invalid Zipcode'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    texts: {
      header: 'Thankyou for filling out the form'
    }
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      /*write the code here*/
    </div>
  );
}
```

I was only able to answer this much:

```
export default function App() {
  const [formInputs, setFormInputs] = useState({});

  const onInputChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    setFormInputs((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <form autoComplete="off">
        {DYNAMIC_FORMS.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.texts.header}>
            <h3>{item.texts.header}</h3>
            {item.inputs && (
              <>
                {item.inputs.map((eachInput) => {
                  const { label, name, type, validation, error } = eachInput;

                  return (
                    <div key={label}>
                      <label>{label}</label>
                      <input {...validation} type={type} name={name} onChange={onInputChange} />
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, because I want to improve on my shortcomings. Thank you!

Comment: Can you rephrase the questions? What I understood is that you want to create a validation scheme for the same dynamic form? Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach,

```js
const VALIDATION_MAP = DYNAMIC_FORMS.reduce((acc, current) => {
  current.inputs?.forEach((input) => {
    acc[input.name] = input.validation;
  });

  return acc;
}, {});

const validate = (input, validation) => {
  const inputLength = input.length;
  const { required, minLength, maxLength } = validation;

  return (
    (required && !inputLength) ||
    (!isNaN(minLength) && inputLength < minLength) ||
    (!isNaN(maxLength) && inputLength > maxLength)
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({});

  const updateFormValue = (name, value) => {
    setFormValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    updateFormValue(name, { value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setFormValues((prev) => {
      const updatedValues = { ...prev };
      Object.entries(VALIDATION_MAP).forEach(([name, validation]) => {
        const input = formValues[name]?.value || "";

        updatedValues[name] = {
          value: input,
          hasValidationError: validate(input, validation)
        };
      });

      return updatedValues;
    });
  };

  const handleInputBlur = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    updateFormValue(name, {
      value,
      hasValidationError: validate(value, VALIDATION_MAP[name])
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form autoComplete="off">
        {DYNAMIC_FORMS.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.texts.header}>
            <h3>{item.texts.header}</h3>
            {item.inputs && (
              <>
                {item.inputs.map((eachInput) => {
                  const { label, name, type, validation, error } = eachInput;
                  const { value, hasValidationError } = formValues[name] || {};
                  return (
                    <div key={label}>
                      <label>{label}</label>
                      <input
                        style={{
                          border: hasValidationError ? "1px red solid" : "solid"
                        }}
                        {...validation}
                        type={type}
                        onBlur={handleInputBlur}
                        value={value || ""}
                        name={name}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                      />
                      {hasValidationError && (
                        <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{error}</div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I did not quite understand the error field for each input, isn't it supposed to be different for each validation? For example, if the password is not provided error can be "Password is required", but if it's provided and it does not meet the min length requirement then the error should be something like "Password should have minimum x characters". Since only a generic error message is given for each input, I have only displayed that in case of a validation error. If you want to show different messages for different cases, instead of having the boolean `hasValidationError` in state ,you can use a string `errorMessage` and have the function `validate` return the required error message